# Why cannot Stack Exchange be visited from 3G?

Tags: discussion

Every time I visit Stack Exchange from Vodafone Albania's 3G network I get a *server not found* notification. I can visit Stack Overflow or Server Fault normally, but not the main site.

Is Albania banned from Stack Exchange developers or is Vodafone banning Stack Exchange?

I asked two other friends to visit Stack Exchange from their 3G network. It is not loading either.

Some Traceroute and DNS records:

```
--- Aug 6, 2014 7:46:19 PM
--- IP (rmnet0) fe80::47c3:b7e7:b20:366d%rmnet0
--- IP (rmnet0) 10.16.227.204
--- Connection: UMTS
```

Reverse DNS on stackexchange.com:

'stackexchange.com' is no IP address

Its IP address is 127.0.0.1.

localhost.

DNS server: 79.171.51.52

---

```
--- Aug 6, 2014 7:46:04 PM
--- IP (rmnet0) fe80::47c3:b7e7:b20:366d%rmnet0
--- IP (rmnet0) 10.16.227.204
--- Connection: UMTS
```

Trace to stackexchange.com:

1 - 127.0.0.1
      localhost

---

```
--- Aug 6, 2014 7:45:49 PM
--- IP (rmnet0) fe80::47c3:b7e7:b20:366d%rmnet0
--- IP (rmnet0) 10.16.227.204
--- Connection: HSPA+
```

DNS records for stackexchange.com

```
stackexchange.com.
TTL=60
A    127.0.0.1
```

(DNS server: 79.171.51.52)

---

```
--- Aug 6, 2014 7:45:10 PM
--- IP (rmnet0) fe80::47c3:b7e7:b20:366d%rmnet0
--- IP (rmnet0) 10.16.227.204
--- Connection: UMTS

PING stackexchange.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.087 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.122 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.126 ms

--- stackexchange.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
min = 0.087 ms
avg = 0.111 ms
max = 0.126 ms
mdev = 0.021 ms
```

---

Comment: Have you run any traces, pulled the DNS records?

Comment: No, I use a Nexus 5. What steps do I take in order to do that?

Comment: I'm sure there are network diagnostic apps you can get free.

Comment: This actually happens to me sometimes too. Toggling my data connection fixes it though so I don't worry about it. // AT&T 3G in the USA. Might not apply

Comment: This is a problem with your 3G network that has nothing to do with Stack Exchange. From the looks of it, your DNS record is directing the domain back to your localhost. Your 3G network probably has corrupted DNS configs.

Comment: Apparently no one can visit StackExchange from this carrier 3G Network. Shame

Comment: @QemalStafa don't just sit there, complain to your carrier! ;)